# MS SQL Auto Increment non Identity Column

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-2008, t-sql, entity-framework-core

I have a table with an auto incrementing identity/primary key column called ID.

```
CREATE TABLE Table1(

[ID] [bigint] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,

[TextContent] [nvarchar](450) NOT NULL,

[Version] [bigint] NOT NULL)
```

When I UPDATE [TextContent], I'd like [Version] to increment by one.  The intent is to have a version for each row that increments anytime the row is updated.

Is there a reasonable way to do this within a single table?  Something to do with computed column values and/or triggers perhaps?

I'm using MSSQL 2008 via Entity Framework.

Thanks for any info!

Comment: Trigger can do the trick. Have a look at Change tracking/CDC (change data capture) also.

Comment: Do you need `Version` column be updated only on update of `TextContent` column, or on update of any column? In case of the latter, have a look at special [rowversion](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182776.aspx) column type, which is castable to bigint as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is after Update as discussed in the comments. It simply increments Version **of this row**.

```
ALTER TRIGGER triggerIncrementUpdate
ON Table1
AFTER UPDATE

AS
BEGIN

UPDATE Table1 SET Version += 1 FROM Table1 INNER JOIN INSERTED As I ON Table1.ID = I.ID

END
```

Comment: I'd say `set version += 1`

Comment: @IvanStarostin you are correct it should be MAX(Version) not MAX(ID).

Comment: No, no, not MAX! I believe his point is row version number. Own counter for each row.

Comment: I really mean `version += 1`. I think this is what this column is for.

Comment: I guess it's not specified exactly what to increment it against. I'm assuming simply incrementing it similar as the ID column. If the other way, increment just for this row then your suggestion is correct.

Comment: you lost a join to `inserted` in this version of trigger

Comment: APologies, I did say "like identity", but the intended function is to have a auto-incremented version for each row that increments with each update. Edited original question to reflect.

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1**

**Try creating a TRIGGER**

```
CREATE TRIGGER incrementValue
ON Table1
FOR Insert
AS 
   Update Table1 
   set columnvalue = columnvalue +1 
   where id in (select id from inserted)
GO
```

**Method 2**

**Using Update Command**

Increment the Column Value each time along with using update command as below

```
UPDATE Tab
   SET Version= Version + 1
 WHERE id = 1
```

Comment: @Simon Ordo  It will update the column value to PrevValue +1 after inserting the value . Let me know if it helps

Answer (score 1):

use `trigger`

```
Create trigger testtrigger
ON Table1
After insert
As
begin
declare @tempIDversion bigint
select @tempIDversion =ID from Table1
  insert into Table1(version) values (@tempIDversion)
END
```

Comment: Somehow this version of trigger does not refer `INSERTED` table and does not support multiple inserts/updates.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe too late, but SQL has the **rowversion** data type that changes automatically on each row insert or update.

It is counter of all the database as inserts or updates as [Microsoft explains here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/rowversion-transact-sql):

> Each database has a counter that is incremented for each insert or update operation that is performed on a table that contains a rowversion column within the database. This counter is the database rowversion. This tracks a relative time within a database, not an actual time that can be associated with a clock. A table can have only one rowversion column. Every time that a row with a rowversion column is modified or inserted, the incremented database rowversion value is inserted in the rowversion column.

This does not increment by one Vs. the previous value of the column as you are trying to achieve, it is just set with the whole database counter of inserts and updates.

But is pretty useful because it only changes when you update a row and always is updated with a higher value, which you can cast to bigint.

Also you can forget about triggers for this purpose.